# website/webservice to fetch data from pc

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to have a webapp/webservice to fetch data from my pc?? Can anyone give me an idea if it is possible....

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how this *data* is going to be exposed from your PC. If you want to read some files from the file system, the server hosting the web application will need to have access to those files. For example you could create a network share and read from this share: `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("\\yourpc\somefile.dat");`

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can have your localhost server too. install wamp, or xampp server, create your php script that gives you data, which can used in you mobile application.